# Google Charts Date Formats

Tags: google-visualization

For some reason the date formatter using a pattern isn't working at all in my application.  One thing that has crossed my mind is that it doesn't allow formatting for the x axis.  Here's a snippet:

```
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
dataTable.addColumn('date', 'YearMonth');
dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Beds');
dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Rooms');
var monthYearFormatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({ pattern: "MMM yyyy" });
monthYearFormatter.format(dataTable, 0);
```

So elsewhere in a loop I do the following:

```
dataTable.addRow(d, currentRow.Beds, currentRow.Rooms]);
```

Where "d" is a valid date.  It isn't formatted at all though, however when I do all of this, it just displays the default format.

Anyone done this before?

Answer (score 16):

In order to format the values on the x-axis, you must use the `format` attribute in the options:

```
hAxis: { format: 'MMM yyyy' }
```

The line:

```
monthYearFormatter.format(dataTable, 0);
```

formats the values in the chart and must be written after the data inserting into the `dataTable` object.

Answer (score 5):

@FrankyFred's answer works only for the labels over the axis and not the toolTip.
If you want to format the text on the toolTip so that what you have is right:

```
var monthYearFormatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({ 
     pattern: "MMM yyyy" 
}); 
monthYearFormatter.format(dataTable, 0);
```