# google line chart with sql datetime

Tags: javascript, sql-server, datetime

I would like to have get my datetime data from SQL Server and pass it to google line chart. I've managed to display other data without datetime. I've no idea how to convert SQL datetime in order to fits google line chart, would like need a little help. I've test with other data and its works. 
In additional, my `Object.Dates` is currently in `String` type to retrieve values from database.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function(){
            $.ajax({
                url : "servletGetSubResult",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(result){
                google.charts.load('current',{
                    'packages' : ['corechart']
                });
                google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
                    drawChart(result);
                });
            }
        });

        function drawChart(result){
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('datetime', 'dates');
            data.addColumn('number', 'result' ); 

            var dataArray= [];
            $.each(result , function(i, obj){
                dataArray.push([obj.dates,obj.result ] );
            });
            data.addRows(dataArray);

            var options = {
                    hAxis: {
                        title : 'testID'
                    },
                    vAxis: {
                      title: 'result'
                    }
                  };
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('piechart_div'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: please provide jsfiddle with some hardcoded data.

Comment: This could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136557/google-charts-date-formats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I've convert my datetime in my SQL to ISO8601 format and also that I've made a mistake in my code that is didn't create a new instantiation for the date.

```
 dataArray.push([obj.dates,obj.result ] )
```

it should be

```
 dataArray.push([ new date(obj.dates),obj.result ] )
```